# querySelector not returning elements with class inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to return the first h1 element inside an iframe I've loaded onto my page.

```
var res = await (await fetch(`https://www.google.com/search?q=${text}`)).text(); //Text is a variable assigned previously
var currentFrame = document.getElementById('frame0');       
var currentDocument = currentFrame.contentWindow.document;
currentDocument.write(res);

var elem = currentDocument.querySelector("h1");
console.log(elem);
```

I'm being able to get the iframe content to show up properly but when I try to print "elem" value whenever the h1 tag of said page has a class it shows up as null.

As in:

```
<h1>Test</h1> //is found properly and console.log prints "Test" which is what I want
```

But on the other hand...

```
<h1 class="classyBoy">Test</h1> //isn't found properly and return null
```

I've tried changing querySelector("h1") to querySelector("h1 *") and querySelector("* h1") but had no success doing so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe maybe this can help you.  You cannot usually get elements that are inside an iframe.

Comment: Hmmmm. But if that was the case why would I still be able to return classless h1s?

Comment: Can't repro: https://jsfiddle.net/drs4qehk/

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I started waiting until currentDocument.body != null the queries started working.